Un Tented pads on PCB
Would you please let me know what would be the purpose of the following Un Tented round pads in a PCB?

Regards

what do you mean by un tented?

@ jsotola it means without silk screen layer(exposed copper)

They are test points, for receiving probes.
After assembling a printed circuit board you want to make sure that the board works as expected. Often this can be done in a Bed of nails tester where multiple probes are connected to the board at the same time, or by applying probes manually.
The test points are placed on relevant nets in the circuitry on input/outputs of circuitry under test.
EDIT:
Example of a test fixture for use in a bed of nails test. Each probe typically interfaces with a test point like that. (It might also probe a non-tented via)

(image borrowed from https://www.proto-electronics.com/blog/an-overview-of-pcb-testing-and-inspection-methods)
You can also read more about test points on https://web.archive.org/web/20240116165414/https://www.pcbdirectory.com/community/what-are-pcb-test-points
and
https://resources.altium.com/p/it-printed-or-component-all-about-pcb-test-points
